# Unable to delete recently created cookie without refreshing

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

So this one really has me stumped and I can't exactly figure out why.

The issue I'm having is when I use an onclick event to set a cookie. Then without reloading the page, trying to remove the cookie is impossible. However, if I reload the page and t then try to remove it,I'm able to.

Here is how I'm setting the cookie:

```
$(".add-prod").one("click", function(){    
    var productParent    = $(this).attr('data-parentstep');
    var productName      = $(this).attr('data-product');
    var productID        = $(this).attr('data-ajaxid');
    var productStep      = $(this).attr('data-productstep');
    Cookies.set('selectedProduct-'+productID,{'id':productID,'name':productName,'step':productStep,'parent':productParent,'thumbnail':productThumbnail},{expires:7,path:''});
});
```

Now setting the cookie works just fine.

The issue comes when I try to remove it WITHOUT reloading the page.

```
$(".remove-this").on("click", function(){
    var unsetId = $(this).attr('data-removeid');
    Cookies.remove('selectedProduct-'+unsetId, { path: '' });
});
```

Clicking a freshly added cookie will not remove itself.
However after I reload and click the ".remove-this" button again, it will delete the cookie.

The only thing I'm thinking that could be the issue is that the cookie is added after the DOM is parsed and essentially can't be found until its re-parsed.
However, I have no idea how to go about doing that.

Any suggestions on how to delete the cookie immediately after creating it in the DOM would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried setting the expiry date of the cookie to a date in the past? Also, are you using a particular jquery cookie plugin?

Comment: I was originally setting it up with raw js but have since started using 
https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie 
js.cookie.js  thinking that there might be some sort of syntactical error I wasn't seeing.

Comment: `document.cookie="username=kwh71787;expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2016 12:00:00 UTC; path=/";` will set a cookie. `document.cookie="username=kwh71787;expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2015 12:00:00 UTC; path=/";` will remove it.

Comment: Dewd, I tried using that but the problem was in the .on("click") function and improper implementation.
Thanks for your help though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, the solution was rather simple.

```
$( document ).on( "click", ".remove-this", function() {
    var unsetId = $(this).attr('data-removeid');
    Cookies.remove('selectedProduct-'+unsetId, { path: '' });
});
```

I wasn't using the .on() function as it was originally intended.
The way I was using it wasn't checking for the cookies that were set after the DOM was parsed.

Comment: Your `on` implementation was fine. I suspect that your timing in running it was what was off. If the DOM object doesn't exist when you run the `on` function (ie the specific `.remove-this` element), the event will not attach to the DOM object. This answer is fine, but it relies on event bubbling to see if the element targeted by the event meets the selector criteria you specifiy in the 2nd option.